# How to set scaleType and adjustViewBounds in Custom ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-imageview

I've created a custom ImageView class, as I wanted to override the onDraw method for my Canvas; however, the XML attributes `scaleType="centerInside"` and `adjustViewBounds="true"` are not being inherited by my custom ImageView class. If I switch to the default ImageView, everything works fine - but how can I have it work in my custom Image View?

In the class below, I'm simply retrieving a bitmap from my application class and drawing it to the canvas; however, when using my CustomImageView - the image is massive and not scaled properly. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Custom ImageView XML:

```
<com.project.app.controls.CustomImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>
```

Custom ImageView Class:

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
    ProjectApp wApp;
    Paint paint;

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        wApp = ProjectApp.createInstance();
        paint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        canvas.drawBitmap(wApp.photoTaken, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: try `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: call canvas.drawBitmap with a Matrix parameter,  get it from grtImageMatrix()

Comment: @Evan B: how did it go?

Answer (score 2):

```
public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    wApp = ProjectApp.createInstance();
    paint = new Paint();
    setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
}
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: You're right. I thought this was pretty straightforward, but it might not be the case for everyone.

Comment: Hey @Carnal, thanks for the reply. I actually had tried that before I posted this question - forgot to add my attempts. I also added that within the onDraw override itself, but to no avail.

Comment: Alright, why do you have WindowImageView for the constructor? Can it even compile?

Comment: @Carnal Sorry, I changed the name to CustomImageView for privacy purposes - forgot to change that. Yes it does compile.

Comment: @Evan B: Alright, what happens if you remove onDraw()?

Comment: Well, I need onDraw() to refresh my canvas.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use fitXY instead so the image will be bound by the constraints of the CustomImageView's layout params (and its parent in this case).

`android:scaleType="fitXY"`